# Override worklight.js

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing an app with IBM MobileFirst Platform and I find an issue with Worklight.js file. Worklight.js is extending Function prototype defining several methods like bind, curry, wrap and so on.

My app is built with aurelia framework an after upgrading the framework to the last version I'm facing a funky issue related to bind extension.

If I comment the bind extension in worklight.js everything seems to work like a charm (don't know why worklight implements its bind version).

Worklight.js file seems to be added to the wlapp package at build time. Is there a way I can override this file so I do not have to modify .wlapp file each time app is built?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to the specific question you've asked is, no, there is no way provided to override worklight.js.  This is the core JavaScript code needed for the MobileFirst Platform client-side to function, and as such the user isn't given any means to modify it - it's injected into your app (i.e., into the WLAPP file) during the build process.

I'm not aware of any specific issues with Aurelia, but have certainly seen cases in the past where an app that uses two different frameworks (e.g., MobileFirst Platform / Worklight, and something else) "fight" with each other because they both want to implement extensions that are not compatible with each other - in which case, one framework or the other usually needs to change to accommodate the other.

If you are a customer with paid support, I'd suggest opening a PMR so we can get our developers to take a look at the issue.

Comment: It's bit weird worklight.js supplies its own extension for the bind function's implementation. This extension has already caused issues in Windows Universal app. So where is the source of this file stored to in my dev machine? Perhaps I can edit this file...

Comment: The "master copy" of the file is in the MobileFirst Platform SDK itself - if you're using Studio (rather than the CLI), it's under your Eclipse "plugins" directory, the exact pathname will vary depending on what MFPF build you're using, but it's simply called "worklight.js".  However, as I said, we don't expose any supported way for a developer to change this file, and if you do so, it could break the product in other ways.

Comment: You "cannot" edit worklight.js, as it gets regenerated on build time. You can edit it post-build time in the generated project, but your changes will get overwritten on the next build.

Comment: What you could do is open a PMR for the development team to decide if this is something that can be changed.

Comment: The issue with worklight.js is about the bind override of the Function.prototype. I'm getting an exception when a bound function is used as a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Angular. Worklight bind makes Angular controller fail to instantiate. The solution is to recover the bind function after worklight is loaded.

```
var bind = Function.prototype.bind;
window.wlCommonInit = function() {
  Function.prototype.bind = bind;
};
```